# Using "sed" to append to end of a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I am currently using `sed` to write to an apache configuration file from `stdin`. I am using `sed` in this script to get around the bash script limition where the calling user does not have privileges to write to the file, so I can't simply `echo "..." >> outputfile.conf`

Here is what I have for *writing* to the file:

```
echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
</VirtualHost>" | sudo sed -n "w/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf"
```

How can I later *append* to this same file?

```
if $enable_ssl; then
    echo "<VirtualHost *:443>
        ...
    </VirtualHost>" | sudo sed <opions-to-sed-here>
fi
```

Comment: Could you simply use `tee -a`?

Comment: Don't you have `/bin/echo` in the system? It is a [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html).
In that case you should simply may be able to use something like `sudo  /bin/echo "whatever" >> outputfile.conf`.

Comment: @Hastur No you can't do that if you are writing to a file owned by root. If am "user" and I run `sudo echo "whatever" >> outputfile.conf` the writing/appending to `output.conf` is done by the shell, not by `echo`. This means I don't have `sudo` permissions when the output is attempted to be written to the file. Isaac's answer using `sudo tee -a` is the correct answer. In that scenario `tee` does have `sudo` permissions and can write to `outputfile.conf`.

Comment: @Makerik thanks, I missed that point. BTW, in order to avoid the use of `tee` (or whatever other executable),  it is needed to write something like `sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "whatever" >> outputfile.conf'` (or `/bin/ash`, `/bin/dash`,  etc etc...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual replacement for shell `>` with higher/different privileges is:

```
echo "replace file content with this line" | sudo tee protectedFile >/dev/null
```

And if you want to append, use `-a`:

```
echo "append this line to file" | sudo tee -a protectedFile >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 7):

Whithout `echo`:

```
string=$'"<VirtualHost *:443> \
        ... \
    </VirtualHost>"'

sudo sed -i '$a\'"${string}"'' file
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to process a files in-place (optionally adding a suffix to the original version).

The sed script:

1. `$` match last line
2. `a\` append text after matching line

It won't work on an empty file though (since there won't be any lines of input to match the last line).

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the double single quote at the end of the sed command?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, if you have `ed` at hand:

```
echo "$
a
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
.
w" | sudo ed protectedFile
```

1. `$` go to last line
2. `a` append, followed by data you want to append terminated by a line containing a single dot
3. `w` stands for *write (file)*

The first two commands can be concatenated (yielding `$a`), yet this won't work on empty file – separately it will, since it means *"go to last line"* (which is a no-op), followed by *"append"* rather than *"append to last line"*, which doesn't really exist.